# Dynamic AND conditions in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, dynamic, multiple-conditions

I have an input String that contains a couple of search terms to find a line in a text including all of the search terms.

For example:

```
String searchTerms = "java stackoverflow conditions";
String [] splittedTerm = searchTerms.split(" ");
```

The search terms are AND connective:

```
if (textLine.contains(splittedTerm[0] && textLine.contains(splittedTerm[1]) && textLine.contains(splittedTerm[2])) start=true;
```

But the number of search terms is dynamic, it alwayse depends on the users request...

So is there any possibility to use the if statement depending on the number of search terms?

Comment: What about a,b,c ... where they are coming from ?

Comment: String equality isn't tested with `==`. And sounds like you want a loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Seems mock up code.

Comment: You should not work with an array but with a List. Lists provide contains() method with which you can check if certain objects (Strings in this case) are within that list.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ That's why it was a comment, instead of a instaclose with duplicate.

Comment: @Elliot: I did a mistake, sorry! Now I've corrected it.

Comment: Missed a paranthesis there `(splittedTerm[0]` :)

Comment: @Suresh: for better understanding I renamed it into textLine

Comment: @Mustafa: Don't be so picky! ;))

Comment: @user3300710 I wont but the compiler definitely will :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the `String[]` that you get after splitiing the String :-

First add all the elements you want to compare in an array, then iterate and compare through first array and array returned from split(). Make sure both arrays are of equal length

```
boolean flag=true;
String searchTerms = "java stackoverflow conditions hello test";
String [] splittedTerm = searchTerms.split(" ");

for(int i=0;i<splittedTerm.length;i++){

  if (!(textLine[i].equals(splittedTerm[i]))){ //textLine is the array containing String literals you want to compare.
   flag=false;
   }

}
start=flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do a loop which iterates over all search terms. If any missmatch is found, set a flag and break the loop. Below the loop you can then check the flag, if it's still true all of your search terms matched.

```
boolean flag = true;
for (String searchTerm : splittedTerm){
    if (!stringToSearch.contains(searchTerm) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (flag)
    all terms matched
else
    one or more terms did not match
```